# nslookup: disable reverse dns lookup on dns server on windows/linux

Tags: dns, nslookup

when you run:
`nslookup domain dns_server`

the utility performs a reverse dns on the dns_server, even if a hostname was provided instead of an IP.

is it possible to disable that feature?

Comment: May I ask do you want to check the server's IP address when using nslookup command?

Answer (score 0):

Most people wouldn't want to disable it. A simple way to break it would be to remove all Reverse lookup (PTR-Records) from DNS. You would also have touch any machine that has permission to update DNS.

Comment: the thing is i don't have ptr records and so I have to wait nslookup to timeout on the ptr records request. i am aware that one solution would be to set ptr records, but I am looking for an option in nslookup if available

Comment: In windows the records involved for a reverse lookup on the domain, read "Same as parent folder)  Host (A) <IPAddress> " Removing them will break DNS completely. If you want to stop reverse lookup on clients then you would remove the PTR Records. I didn't read your request clearly. To answer your question, No, you can't prevent a reverse lookup on a Domain without breaking DNS, and most people would not want to prevent the lookup in the first place. The clients wouldn't operate properly, no one could send/receive email, etc... What is the goal here?

Comment: hey Larry, i am not looking to eliminate PTR records from the DNS ecosystem. What i am looking is to have nslookup stop trying to get those records for my DNS resolver for every query i make since i know that those records do not exist and it just makes the resolution of my queries slower.

Comment: OK, so you don't want NSLOOKUP querying your DNS server for PTR records.  Well, first off, if you don't have the PTR records you should add them, DNS works a lot better if they are there. *Second, nslookup will only look at  PTR Records if you query it with an IP Address.*  DNS uses the A records to convert a name to an address, and it uses the PTR records to convert an address to a name. Both have value to your DNS ecosystem.  So if you want it "to stop trying to get those records" then dont use IP addresses.  That's probably not what you want to hear, give me an example of a query you use.